# Adjust Default Zoom in lightweight charts

Tags: tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

Does anyone know if there is a way to adjust the default zoom used on trading view lightweight charts when double-clicking the x-axis? To my knowledge, double-clicking evokes [resetTimeScale](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#resettimescale) but there doesn't seem to be any way to set which value is used as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default zoom is determined by the [`barSpacing`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/TimeScaleOptions#barspacing) property of the time scale options.

You can calculate what the barSpacing is for the current state of a chart by using the [`getVisibleLogicalRange`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#getvisiblelogicalrange) method on the time scale API and the width of the time scale.

For example:

```js
const visibleLogicalRange = chart.timeScale().getVisibleLogicalRange();
const currentBarSpacing = chart.timeScale().width() / (visibleLogicalRange.to - visibleLogicalRange.from);

// change the current barSpacing
chart.timeScale().applyOptions({
  barSpacing: 12, // default is 6
})
```